# Download from protected with password FTP server with use of CFNetwork

Tags: ios, xcode

I am making an app that can dowload from FTP server that protected with username and password file and saved it in documentsDirectory. I have managed to download file directly from HTTP, save and dispaly it. Now I wish to do so from FTP. Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)download:(id)sender
{
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.image.png";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData )
{
    NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename3.png"];

    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}

}

-(IBAction)viewImage:(id)sender
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename3.png"];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];


[imageV setImage:img];
}
```

Can anyone please point me to CFNetwork example. I need to connect to ftp server, list files in folder and download them. Already looked at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFFTPTasks/CFFTPTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH9-SW1 but it`s not so clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [BlackRaccoon](https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon) to work with FTP.